# Render partial to String in view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

How can I render a partial to a String in Ruby on Rails 4.2, since `render_to_string` is deprecated?

Something like:

```
 rendered_string = render_to_string partial: 'forgotten_orders/soonest_manufacturing_date', locals: { forgotten_order: forgotten_order, soonest_manufacturing_date: soonest_manufacturing_date }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use `render`.  My demo:

In my view:

```
<% foo = render 'foo_thing', bar:"formal bar" %>
<%= foo %>
```

In `_foo_thing.html.erb`:

```
<%= "This bar is a #{bar}" %>
```

And on my screen:

```
 This bar is a formal bar
```

Comment: Yep I guess `#render` does work in a helper, but this answer doesn't show a helper method!

Answer (score 0):

Well, render_to_string actually is not deprecated, it still exists. The implementation however has changed according to the
[render_to_string doc.](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/render_to_string) I haven't really used it in a while, but I'd expect it to still work for you.